# Increment or decrement values of multiple spinners

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-spinner

I have a single spinner on my webpage which is working fine. Below is my code.

```
<div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="0" style="width: 67px; height: 62px; text-align: center; font-size:35px;">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

(function ($) {
  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1);
  });
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1);
    var current_val = $('.spinner input').val();
    if(current_val <= 0)
    {
        $('.spinner input').val(0);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Now I want to place this spinner multiple times on my webpage. The issue is when i click + or - button all the spinner values are incrementing or decrementing at same time. `How can I do this dynamically? When I click on + / - button of one spinner then only that spinner values should change, others should remain same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.`

```
(function ($) {
  $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find("input").val( parseInt($(this).parent().find("input").val(), 10) + 1);
    //$(this).parent().find("input")
  });
  $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find("input").val( parseInt($(this).parent().find("input").val(), 10) - 1);
    var current_val = $(this).parent().find("input").val();
    if(current_val <= 0)
    {
        $(this).parent().find("input").val(0);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Try using `$(this).parent().find("input")` rather than `$(".spinner input")`

Comment: Every time you use `$(".spinner input")`, you access every input in every spinner tag because they all have the same class.

Comment: I have edited the code based on your suggestion. Please see above.. Nothing is happening

Comment: I would also try replacing `$('.spinner .btn:last-of-type')` with `$('.spinner .input-group-btn-vertical .btn:last-of-type')`, and the same for `first-of-type`. This may affect the behavior of `.parent()`.

Comment: I also tried, but nothing happen like previous

Comment: Any body can help in this regards??